# CSS - image refuses to vertical align in middle

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment

The image is not in the middle of the div.

Tried various solutions, such as line-height and vertical-align:middle;

```css
.trio {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.wp-image-6731,
.wp-image-6733,
.wp-image-6733 {
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="trio">
  <img class="wp-image-6733 size-full aligncenter" src="https://proef-domein.nl/chiropractic/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2.png" alt="" width="103" height="31">
</div>
```

Comment: [Yes it is](https://jsfiddle.net/9adrwp2n/)

Comment: Right click the image > Inspect element. Check which other styles are being applied. There must be some other CSS that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: Alternatively you could use flexbox to do this: `.trio{height:80px; display:flex; align-items:center;}`

Comment: You were right @Moob, images were given the rule display:block and margin-left/right auto. After adapting, it worked. Thanks!